# Curious slowness of EF vs SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, entity-framework, ado.net

In a heavily multi-threaded scenario, I have problems with a particular EF query. It's generally cheap and fast:

```
Context.MyEntity
  .Any(se => se.SameEntity.Field == someValue        
     && se.AnotherEntity.Field == anotherValue
     && se.SimpleField == simpleValue
     // few more simple predicates with fields on the main entity
     );
```

This compiles into a very reasonable SQL query:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Field1] AS [Field1]
        FROM  [dbo].[MyEntity] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SameEntity] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[SameEntity_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE (N'123' = [Extent2].[SimpleField]) AND (123 = [Extent1].[AnotherEntity_Id]) AND -- further simple predicates here -- ) AS [Filter1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AnotherEntity] AS [Extent3] ON [Filter1].[AnotherEntity_Id1] = [Extent3].[Id]
    WHERE N'123' = [Extent3].[SimpleField]
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

The query, in general, has optimal query plan, uses the right indices and returns in tens of **milliseconds** which is completely acceptable.

However, when a critical number of threads (<=40) starts executing this query, the performance on it drops to tens of **seconds**.

There are no locks in the database, no queries are writing data to these tables and it reproduces very well with a database that's practically isolated from any other operations. The DB resides on the same physical machine and <strike>the machine is not overloaded at any point, i.e. has plenty of spare CPU, memory and other resources</strike> **the CPU is overloaded by this operation**.

Now what's really bizarre is that when I replace the EF `Any()` call with `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` with the copy-pasted SQL (also using parameters), the problem magically disappears. Again, this reproduces very reliably - **replacing the `Any()` call with copy-pasted SQL increases the performance by 2-3 orders of magnitude** .

---

An attached profiler (dotTrace) sampling shows that the threads seem to all spend their time in the following method:

[image: dotTrace sample]

Is there anything I've missed or did we hit some ADO.NET / SQL Server cornercase?

---

**MORE CONTEXT**

The code running this query is a Hangfire job. For the purpose of test, a script queues a lot of jobs to be performed and up to 40 threads keep processing the job. Each job uses a separate `DbContext` instance and it's not really being used a lot. There are a few more queries before and after the problematic query and they take expected times to execute.

We're using many different Hangfire jobs for similar purposes and they behave as expected. Same with this one, *except when it gets slow* under high concurrency (of exact same jobs). Also, just switching to SQL on this particular query fixes the problem.

The profiling snapshot above is representative, all the threads slow down on this particular method call and spend the vast majority of their time on it.

---

**UPDATE**

I'm currently re-running a lot of those checks for sanity and errors. The *easy* reproduction means it's still on a remote machine to which I can't connect using VS for debugging.

One of the checks showed that my previous statement about free CPU was false, the CPU was not entirely overloaded but multiple cores were in fact running on full capacity for the whole duration of the long running jobs.

Re-checking everything again and will come back with updates here.

Comment: That method just waits for the server to respond. It is not at fault. (I don't know what is.)

Comment: At the point in time where it's slow, pause the debugger and capture a screenshot of the Parallel Stacks window. We need a sample of what the threads are doing.

Comment: As stated above, the profiler show the hot path - all the threads slow down on this method. I'm suspecting either a corner case in the SQL connector or maybe a series of events that causes SQL itself to block/slow down (even with free resources).

Comment: ADO.NET is being used for a trillion transactions per second on 100m servers. It does not have bugs anymore ;-) (approximately). Yes, I suspect a SQL problem also but it is triggered by app code. Maybe we'll find one thread doing something suspicious or unexpected. Since we have no other lead to go on you should invest the 2min required to perform the test.

Comment: Also, check while it happens for memory grants. How did you determine that there is no blocking? (Trying to see if you made a mistake there.) What's the CPU and IO utilization on the server at that time?

Comment: Have you tried changing `Any()` to `AnyAsync()` ? ( not a small change, I guess )

Comment: So yeah, there were a few flaws in the debugging. This sort of thing happens after you spend many hours on it and start questioning your sanity. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faulty initial assumptions. The SQL in the question was obtained by pasting the code into LINQPad and having it generate the SQL.

After attaching an SQL profiler to the actual DB used, it showed a *slightly different* SQL involving outer joins, which are suboptimal and didn't have a proper index in place.

It remains a mystery why LINQPad generated different SQL, even though it's using the same `EntityFramework.dll`, but the original problem is resolved and all that remains is to optimize the query.

Many thanks for everyone involved.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try as shown below and see whether is there any performance improvement or not ...

```
Context.MyEntity.AsNoTracking()
  .Any(se => se.SameEntity.Field == someValue        
     && se.AnotherEntity.Field == anotherValue
     && se.SimpleField == simpleValue
    );
```

Comment: ``Any()`` returns a bool while ``AsNoTracking()`` is an extension method on ``IQueryable``...

Comment: AsNoTracking() was tried previously and had no effect. In fact, the SQL query returns just one number, so tracking shouldn't be responsible (in the reasonable world anyway).

Comment: hmm..I saw that you have found the solution.Great :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are reusing the context in a loop. Doing so may create many objects during your performance test and giving the garbage collector a lot of work to do.